# How to store date and time ranges without overlap in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the right query to check if date and time ranges overlap in the MySQL table, here is the table:

```
id      pickup_date     pickup_time     return_date     return_time
1       2016-05-01      12:00:00        2016-05-31      13:00:00
2       2016-07-01      12:00:00        2016-07-04      15:00:00
```

Here are the data about every reservation which is coming and need to be checked against the "Reservations" table:

```
pickup_date = '2016-04-01';
pickup_time = '12:00:00'
return_date = '2016-05-01';
return_time = '13:00:00'
```

with this data the reservation overlap the one in the database. Take a note: the new reservation can be in the past or in the future.

**EDIT (as proposed by spencer7593, this is the working version so far):**

```
    SET @new_booking_pickup_date = '2016-04-01';
    SET @new_booking_pickup_time = '12:00:00';
    SET @new_booking_return_date = '2016-05-01';
    SET @new_booking_return_time = '13:00:00';

    SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE NOT 
( CONCAT(@new_booking_pickup_date,' ',@new_booking_pickup_time) > CONCAT(return_date,' ',return_time) + INTERVAL 0 DAY OR CONCAT(@new_booking_return_date,' ',@new_booking_return_time) < CONCAT(pickup_date,' ',pickup_time) + INTERVAL 0 DAY);
```

, so this query will result:

```
id      pickup_date     pickup_time     return_date     return_time
1       2016-05-01      12:00:00        2016-05-31      13:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to determine if a given period doesn't overlap with another period.

For ease of expressing the comparison, for period 1, we'll let the begin and end be represented by b1 and e1. For period 2, b2 and e2.

There is no overlap if the following is true:

```
  b1 > e2 OR e1 < b2
```

(We can quibble whether equality of b1 and e2 would be considered an overlap or not, and adjust as necessary.)

The negation of that test would return TRUE if there was an overlap...

```
 NOT (b1 > e2 OR e1 < b2)
```

So, to find out if there is a row that overlaps with the proposed period, we would need a query that tests whether a row is returned...

Let's assume that table we are going to check has columns `st` and `et` (DATETIME) representing the beginning and ending of each period.

To find rows with an overlap with a proposed period bounded by `b1` and `e1`

```
  SELECT t.* FROM t WHERE NOT (b1 > t.et OR e1 < t.st)
```

So for a query to just check for the existence of an overlapping row, we could do something like this:

```
  SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE NOT (b1 > t.et OR e1 < t.st))
```

That's pretty simple.

---

It's going to look a lot more complicated when we make the adjustment for the (inexplicable) split of the `date` and `time` components of a datetime into separate columns (as shown in the question).

It's just a straightforward matter of combining the separate date and time values together into a single value of `DATETIME` datatype.

All we need to do is substitute into our query above an appropriate conversion, e.g.

```
  st =>  CONCAT(pickup_date,' ',pickup_time) + INTERVAL 0 DAY
  et =>  CONCAT(return_date,' ',return_time) + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

Same for `b1` and `e1`.

Doing that substitution, coming up with the final query, is left as an exercise for whoever decided that storing date and time as separate columns was a good idea.

Comment: I omitted some requirements for the above to work... it must be guaranteed that b1,e1, st, et are **`DATETIME`** datatypes, and be guaranteed to be TRUE that... **`(b1 <= e1 AND st <= et)`** (This guarantees that the start of the period is BEFORE the end of the period, which in turn guarantees that both the start and end are non-NULL.)

Comment: do I need + INTERVAL 0 DAY because (+INTERVAL) is not supported by DQL (I need the query in the DQL not SQL)

Comment: I use the `+ INTERVAL 0 DAY` to make it explicit that I'm wanting a `DATETIME`... to do the conversion if necessary. If the column in the table was already DATETIME, I wouldn't need it. (The datatypes of your columns `pickup_date` and `pickup_time` weren't specificed, I assumed worst case they were character, and used CONCAT to combine them.)  I could just as easily use `CONVERT(foo,DATETIME)`, or `STR_TO_DATE(foo,'%Y-%m-%d %T')`.  When I'm playing string games with dates and times, I'm usually getting values for a range check, and I'm already doing a `+ INTERVAL n DAY` on one side or other

Comment: Yes,  pickup_date is DATE, pickup_time is TIME, and return_date is DATE and return_time is TIME, so I don't need +INTERVAL 0 DAYS

Comment: I never work with `DATE` and `TIME` in separate columns. so I'm not familiar with any means to combine them, other than convert to string and concatenate and then convert back to DATETIME. (If I ever need just the date or time portion, I'll use `DATE_FORMAT()` function.)  On a performance note, the expressions in the WHERE clause will need to be evaluated for every row in the table. That construct prevents MySQL from performing an index range scan operation.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to convert to datetime, if you want to perform a string comparison instead. You would just eed to guarantee that the strings are formatted *identically* and in a *canonical* format, so the string comparison is equivalent to a datetime comparison. (e.g four digit year, two digit month, two digit day... with identical separators...).

Comment: Looks like the MySQL **`TIMESTAMP()`** function could be used to combine the two into a single DATETIME... **`TIMESTAMP(pickup_date, pickup_time)`**  I've not tested that  [**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)